# Quarto Unable to Render Python

Tags: python, r, quarto, windows-11

I **cannot** render Quarto documents that contain `Python` code chunks.

I **can** successfully render Quarto documents that contain `R` code chunks.

## Error message

The error message I receive is:

```
==> quarto preview example.Qmd --to html --no-watch-inputs --no-browse

ERROR: Unable to render example.Qmd

Stack trace:
    at fileExecutionEngineAndTarget (file:///C:/PROGRA~1/Quarto/bin/quarto.js:41260:15)
    at async renderContexts (file:///C:/PROGRA~1/Quarto/bin/quarto.js:72183:32)
    at async renderFormats (file:///C:/PROGRA~1/Quarto/bin/quarto.js:72234:22)
    at async file:///C:/PROGRA~1/Quarto/bin/quarto.js:98062:24
    at async Command.fn (file:///C:/PROGRA~1/Quarto/bin/quarto.js:98059:25)
    at async Command.execute (file:///C:/PROGRA~1/Quarto/bin/quarto.js:8104:13)
    at async quarto (file:///C:/PROGRA~1/Quarto/bin/quarto.js:114968:5)
    at async file:///C:/PROGRA~1/Quarto/bin/quarto.js:114986:9
```

## Reprex

It's not quite a reproducible example, but it's the best I can achieve given the error.

I am using the following CLI syntax to render an example document which lives on my Desktop:

```
quarto render Desktop\example.Qmd
```

The contents of `Desktop\example.Qmd` are (when I attempt python - I just switch the 'python' to 'r' when I want to render R.):

````
---
title: Example
subtitle: Example
format: html
---

```{python}
2 + 2
```
````

## SetUp

### Machine

Microsoft Windows 11 Home

Version 10.0.22621 Build 22621

### Software Versions

All of the paths listed below are on my `PATH` Environment variable.

- R 4.3.0 (Path: `C:\Program Files\R\`)
- Python 3.12.1 (Path: `C:\Program Files\Python312\`)
- Quarto 1.4.547 (Path: `C:\Program Files\Quarto`)

### Jupyter

Following [Using Python](https://quarto.org/docs/computations/python.html#installation) from Quarto, i used the following command to install Jupyter:

`py -m pip install jupyter`

Which was installed at `C:\Users\me\appdata\roaming\python\python312\site-packages`

Running the Quarto command `quarto check jupyter` returns:

```
Quarto 1.4.547
[>] Checking Python 3 installation....OK
      Version: 3.12.1
      Path: C:/Program Files/Python312/python.exe
      Jupyter: 5.7.1
      Kernels: python3

[>] Checking Jupyter engine render....OK
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have determined that the issue is using the `.Qmd` extension as opposed to the `.qmd` extension.

Using the `.Qmd` extension works when rendering `R` codechunks, but causes an error when rendering `Python` chunks.

When I change the extension to `.qmd`, the `python` version runs successfully.

I would expect the behavior across both languages to be the same (either generate an error for both languages or successfully render both documents), so I have filed an [issue on Github](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/issues/8454).